# Is there any way to convert an entire snowflake create table script to azure sql script?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, azure-sql-server

I am trying to load data from a couple of snowflake tables [200-300 columns] into azure sql server. Is there a way to convert the datatypes automatically or to convert the entire table creation script ?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the ddl into a text editor and use find-and-replace to change the datatypes

Answer (score 0):

There are tools online that can assist here (Your mileage may vary)

Example: https://www.jooq.org/translate/